# Show global win32 output in Visual Studio

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012

I want to capture the global win32 output in Visual Studio 2012. I can do this with [DebugView](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/using-debugview-to-catch-debug-output-of-net-program), but i would like to have this kind of output in a Visual Studio window. I can not just use the default Debug output, because i am developing SharePoint solutions and attaching to an other process doesn't work.

Is there a way to capture global win32 output in Visual Studio 2012 or is there an Add In out there, which captures this kind of output?

Edit:

Just to clarify: I use C# and i can write Debug-Output. I can't attach to the process and want to capture the global win32 debug output.

Comment: DebugView does not display "global win32 output".  It only displays strings passed to the OutputDebugString() winapi function.  The general way to get text to appear in a debugger logging window.  Only a debugger can display it, its WaitForDebugEvent() function call completes with the DEBUG_EVENT.dwDebugEventCode set to OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_EVENT.  I suspect you'll be much ahead with the Trace class or a logging library like NLog.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, but i cant change to an other Debug Solution atm. In other solutions i use the SharePoint intern ULS-Log and just use the normal Visual Studio-Debug tools, but in this solution i can't use them and have to use DebugView.

Comment: Why can't you attach to other processes?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Idk. I get errors when i try it.

Comment: What kind of errors? Please be a bit more verbose, we want to help you and need to understand the problem.

Comment: @ThomasWeller "Unable to start debugging on the web server." And when i try starting it the whole VS crashes. Because of this, and the fact i am working with multiple solutions at the same time, i wanted to get my debug output inside of VS. But it looks like there isn't such a feature i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: there is currently no option to show this output inside of Visual Studio. When i find an AddOn i will update this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using the following ...

```
OutputDebugString(str);
```

You could have this on a debug macro, I would use something similar when developing.

```
#if DEBUG_TO_VS2012 == 1
   #define DPRINTF( x ) OutputDebugString( x )
#else
   #define DPRINTF( X ) printf( x )
#endif
```

Hopefully this easy method helps.

Comment: I use C#. But i think this is similar to Debug.WriteLine(string str);. The problem is, that i cant attach to the process outputting the strings.

Comment: Let me look into it - ... Just thinking of easy options - have you tried directing the output to a file - and then just displaying that file in your c# app  (update the read every second or so)..?

Comment: Try having a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005874/how-to-get-the-error-message-with-c-sharp - it might need a little changing Alex.

Comment: i can capture the debug output with DebugView, as i linked in the question. I just hoped there would be some kind of capture in Visual Studio, because reading stack traces without the code is annoying.
I don't want to rewite the howl Application.

Comment: thats not the kind of solution im looking for : /, but thanks for this idea.

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938734/alternatives-to-debugview  - it shows alternatives to debugView - this might at least guide you in the right direction.